# Angular: Unable to subscribe to the latest value of BehaviorSubject in sibling component through routes

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to trigger an event in component B through it's sibling component A. I have routes configured in this way

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: FileUploadComponent,
      children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'zipUpload', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'zipUpload', component: ZipFileUploadComponent },
        { path: 'reportsView', component: ReportsViewComponent }
      ]
    }
];
```

I have written BehaviorSubject logic in the service class. Service is AppModule level.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppState {

  public canShowAlerts$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public showAlerts(booleanData: boolean): void {
    this.canShowAlerts$.next(booleanData);
  }
```

In component A, after subscribing to an API response and if the response is success, I'm setting the BehaviorSubject value to true and later I'm navigating to component B and want to display a success alert.

Component A

```
this.someService.uploadFile(data)
    .subscribe(
      (response) => {
        if (response === 'Success') {
         this.appState.showAlerts(true);
         this.router.navigate(['../reportsView'],  {relativeTo: this.route});
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        this.errors = error;
      });
```

Component B

```
constructor(private appState: AppState) {
        this.appState.canShowAlerts$.subscribe(
            (response) => {
                if (response === true) {
                    this.myData = 'Successfully uploaded zip files';
                }
            }
        )}
```

Problem is, Component B is not fetching the true value set in component A and its fetching the initial false value. Is this because value is set in it's sibling component? Or any other issue? Please suggest.

Comment: In which module's providers you have added the service ?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan app.module level

Comment: What is the AppState class? Is it also a Service? Is it somehow setup to mirror the members of FileUploadService?

Comment: @Protagonist does component B use OnPush change detection strategy?

Comment: @Miller Appstate is just a normal service having just BehaviorSubject and method declaration

Comment: @DanMacák No. component B is not using OnPush change detection strategy

Comment: Why have you shown the code for FileUploadService when the components are injected with instances of AppState?

Comment: Exactly, what is the relation between FileUploadService and AppState?

Comment: @Miller My Bad. I have updated the code

Comment: In that case I agree with @SurenSrapyan something must be wrong with how AppState is being registered with the injector. If you put some logging in its constructor I'm sure you'll see multiple instances of it are being created

Comment: @Miller I put the console.log in the constructor of AppState and I see that it's logging only once

Comment: Well, I'm flummoxed ... I'll post an answer with some code and we'll progressively try to narrow this down...

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Problem was I was injecting the AppState service class in both AppModule and provider section of the component which is using AppState. So it worked after I removed from the provider section of the Component.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to encapsulate the BehaviorSubject and then attach some logging to it as follows:

- Rename your BehaviorSubject to a new `private` member
- Change `canShowAlerts$` to be a public Observable.
- add some logging using `.do` to verify the emissions are as you expect

eg:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppState {

  private canShowAlertsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public canShowAlerts$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    console.log('AppState - constructed');
    this.canShowAlerts$ = this.canShowAlertsSubject
      .asObservable()
      .do((canShow: boolean) => {
        console.log('AppState - canShowAlerts$ emitted ' + currentValue);
      });
  }

  public showAlerts(booleanData: boolean): void {
    this.canShowAlertsSubject.next(booleanData);
  }
}
```

Based on your code, you should only see the following lines logged:

```
AppState - constructed
AppState - canShowAlerts$ emitted true
```

If ComponentB has failed to attach correctly, then you will not see the second line logged